# Getting link of uploaded app

Tags: android

I developed an app and I uploaded into google play yesterday and I uploaded in alpha section. But after publishing, I'm still unable to find it in google play store even after enter the exact app name. Are there any options where the registerer in google play will get the app path in his profile page. Please suggest me how to get it. its been almost 20 hours since I published my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching it with:

```
play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>
```

If found, note it might take time (1 hour to few days) for google to distribute to all google play's servers.

Comment: I tried this one. But cannot find it. I think I have to wait more.